# Search for an answer to a question by a user

Tags: feature-request, support, search

I can search for my own questions and answers with `is:q user:399694` and `is:a user:399694`. I want to have a search that does this: gets a list of all the questions by a user, then gives me a list of all the answers to those questions by a certain user.

Is there a way to do this? If not, I would love this to be added.

Comment: Probably only in SEDE. I don't think our search function is that advanced.

Answer (score 1):

In the 6 to 8 weeks you have to wait to get this implemented, you can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1059568?UserId=102999), if you allow for a lag of up to 7 days:

```sql
select a.id as [Post Link]
     , a.body
     , a.owneruserid as [User Link]
     , a.score
     , a.creationdate
     , a.lasteditdate
from posts a
inner join posts q on q.id = a.parentid
where q.owneruserid = ##userid:int?102999##
order by q.creationdate desc
```

Running today for your main site this will give:

[image: result with all answers]

Keep in mind that SEDE will get its refresh on Sunday at 03:00 UTC. Do try the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and say "Hi" in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede)